# Merge [replacement] and [substitutes] tags into [substitutions]?

Tags: discussion, tagging, retag-request

Should we merge [replacement] and [substitutes] tags into the [substitutions] tag? [substitutions] seems to be very popular and the other 2 haven't been used much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, [replacement](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replacement) and [substitutes](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substitutes) are already synonyms of [substitutions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substitutions) - see its [synonyms page](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/substitutions/synonyms). If for example you type replacement in the tag field, [substitutions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substitutions) will show up instead (with an "also: replacement" below) and you'll end up with the right tag.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now